# Undertake An Extension

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I am a bit confused about "undertake":

[link](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/06/27/us-ukraine-crisis-ceasefire-idUSKBN0F22GL20140627)

> The ceasefire ***extension had been undertaken***, it said, in line with a deadline set by EU leaders for Ukrainian rebels to agree to ceasefire verification arrangements, return border checkpoints to Kiev authorities and free hostages including detained monitors of the OSCE rights and security watchdog.

Is "to undertake an extension" is slightly odd-sounding, compared to "to undertake a task/job/investigation/experiment"?

Comment: Yes, it's "slightly odd-sounding", but it's probably [the best of a bad bunch](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-best-of-a-bad-bunch-lot), in the circumstances. You should have more faith in Reuters journalists like [Richard Balmforth](http://blogs.reuters.com/richard-balmforth/) and [Ken Wills](http://blogs.reuters.com/ken-wills/). They wouldn't have their jobs if they couldn't write decent English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would "The ***task of extending the ceasefire*** had been undertaken..." be better?

Comment: I have no reason to think so, since it subtly shifts the meaning. To repeat - you should assume the writer and editor know exactly what they mean, and how to express it. These are skilled people largely working in their "specialist subject". I therefore assume they meant *acceptance of an obligation to extend the ceasefire* to be either a nuance or the totality of the intended sense. But I'd probably have to read the entire piece to say that with any great confidence. I might just do that for interest's sake, but I haven't *yet*.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. It is a *little* odd in this context, because "the ceasefire extension" is not an action. (If anything, it's a lack of action!) However, I think it's still understandable enough: the *action* being undertaken is to extend the ceasefire.<sup>†</sup>

I think the word was used here because of its connotations. "To undertake" suggests a sincere attempt at something, whether you succeed or fail. Also, the noun "undertaking" can mean a promise to do something, and it would be very *normal* to refer to an agreed ceasefire as an "undertaking" by both sides.

(Incidentally, what I find worse about the linked article is that "it", of the "it said" in your quoted section, is unclear. Is "it" the announcement, mentioned in the previous sentence/paragraph? Is "it" Poroshenko's presidential website, from the sentence/paragraph before that? Is "it" Ukraine? All of these amount to the same thing, but it gives me a mental "stumble" when I read the sentence!)

---

<sup>†</sup> As discussed in the comments, it's not 100% clear whether that means the undertaking is *to obey an extended ceasefire* or just to *negotiate* it. But that has no bearing on the use of "undertake".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you've nailed it. We'd have to check dates, because an alternative reading might well be supported by discovering that the "narrative reference time" is actually *before* the start of the extension. To wit: that what was "undertaken" was a *diplomatic acceptance of the need for an extension*, rather than the actual act of *"implementing"* it.

Comment: That's entirely possible; while I *think* my reading is correct, the whole sentence seems filled with "diplomatic acceptance" language rather than actually *committing* to anything. ("They agreed to undertake to arrange to verify..." :-P) I shall amend my answer ("it's clear enough") accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think

> ceasefire extension

is OK. A *ceasefire* is an agreement between two sides (not to fight), and they have a start and end time. So the *extension* is just modifying that agreement.

> had been undertaken

just means it that extension period had started in the past and is currently in force.

I couldn't say if it is proper writing style though.